# Access rights for Preview.app in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

when I try to run

```
tell application "Preview"
activate
open "/Users/username/Desktop/Testdokument 1 Kopie.pdf"
end tell
```

I receive an error message that I do not have the rights to do so. When I open the PDF manually first it works with the script in a second attempt, too.

How can I use the script to open the PDF in first place?
Thank you!

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2)

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Preview"
activate
end tell

do shell script "open -a Preview " & quoted form of ( "/Users/username/Desktop/Testdokument 1 Kopie.pdf")
```

It's not pretty but does the job ;-)

Comment: If **Preview** is the _default application_ on your system, in other words you have not set some other _application_ to open **PDF** _files_, then `tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/path/to/filename.pdf"` will open it in **Preview** without it first having been opened manually.